# prepareForSegue called after viewDidLoad in segue from ViewController to TableViewController

Tags: ios5, storyboard

I am building an iOS 5 app with oauth integrated. My storyboard consists of a container NavigationController, with a rootViewController, and two viewControllers segueing from the rootView. When the app is launched, i perform a check to see if an access token is present, and direct the user accordingly.

```
// rootViewController.m viewDidAppear (i need to perform this check anytime the user is brought to the root view, say for e.g. he logs-out.)

if (accessToken) {
    BOOL didAuth = [GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch authorizeFromKeychainForName:@"app name: service" authentication:accessToken

    if (didAuth){

        //perform segue to main User View (which is a TableViewController)
    }

    else{

        //perform segue to sign-in controller, and direct the user to main view from there.
    }

}
```

I have a couple of questions:

1. Is such a setup 'valid' as per Apple's Interface Guidelines?
2. I noticed that the prepareForSegue method in rootViewController gets called *after* the mainUserView's (which is a TableViewController) viewDidLoad. Is this standard behavior? I understand that this is the case for popovers, but for segues from a standard ViewController to a TableViewController?

Thanks!